# Excel: Extending lookup to new cells without excending vectors

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I use the VLOOKUP function to fill a value based on a lookup_value in the same row, looking for a lookup_vector and result_vector on a different sheet.

It's for people borrowing items with an ID, so in sheet1, column A I got IDs and in column B I got the lookup function. Sheet2 has all borrowers and their specific item ID:

Sheet1:
| Item | Person |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 123    | [lookup]            |
| 456| [lookup]            |

Sheet2:
| Person| Item |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Bob    | 123            |
| Steve| 456            |

And my lookup function looks somewhat like this:

```
=IF(ISNA(XLOOKUP(A2;'Sheet2'!B2:B10;'Sheet2'!A2:A10));"Not lent out";XLOOKUP(A2;'Sheet2'!B2:B10;'Sheet2'!A2:A10))
```

The problem happens when I extend the lookup function. Sure, the lookup_value(A2 in the above example) is being extended as well, which is correct - lookup in row 3 should use A3 as the lookup_value.

But why on earth does Excel think the lookup_vector and result_vector need to change to A3:A11?

Other than pasting the correct VLOOKUP-Function and correcting the lookup_value manually, is there a good way of extending the function correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute reference if you don't want the range to change.

> An absolute reference in Excel refers to a reference that is "locked" so that rows and columns won't change when copied. Unlike a relative reference, an absolute reference refers to an actual fixed location on a worksheet.

> By default, all references in Excel formulas are relative. You can convert a relative reference to absolute reference with by using dollar sign ($) characters.

```
=IF(ISNA(XLOOKUP(A2;'Sheet2'!B2:B10;'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$10));"Not lent out";XLOOKUP(A2;'Sheet2'!B2:B10;'Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$10))
```

**Sources:**

[Absolute reference](https://exceljet.net/glossary/absolute-reference)

[Relative reference](https://exceljet.net/glossary/relative-reference)

Comment: Neat, I didn't know absolute references were a thing. Thanks! Ended up doing it differently btw: I simply used B:B/A:A to match the full column, which was an option after a small change to the layout. Makes for easier maintenance.